# How to implement Deeplinking in MarketingCloudSdk salesforce push notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am new to deep linking in Android push notifications.

When i studied about `deep linking` i found **two methods** **to navigate in** `deep linking`

1. Is to set `Intent filter` in `manifest` file.
2. Navigate using an `Intent` from notification click listener.

**Which method is usually implemented in the push notification scenario ?**

And i can't find anything related to deep linking in Salesforce MarketingCloudSdk doucmentation.

If someone has **any code related to notification click listener of** `salesforce MarketingCloudSdk` or know how to implement `deep linking` in it. **Please help**.

**Below is the link to their documentation**

http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/implement-sdk-google.html